# Laravel builder sort by relations

Tags: laravel

I use this package for filter: `https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable`

I need do filter by sort posts by category.

I have a function in custom filter:

```
public function byCategory($categoriesId = [])
{
    return $this->builder->categories->whereIn('id', $categoriesId);
}
```

But I get error undifined `categories`. Why? In model I have relation with categories.

Model posts:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Categories');
}
```